# Handle automatic IP input?

Tags: javascript, html, ip

How to solve it:

```
<input id="ip" onkeyup="IP();">
```

**This is script:**

```
function IP(){
                document.getElementById('IP').value = document.getElementById('IP').value.replace(/[^0-9 .]/g,"");
                var ip = document.getElementById('IP').value;
                ipparts= new Array();
                ipparts = ip.split('.');
                L=((ipparts.length)-1);                    
                if(L<=2){
                    if (ipparts[L]>=26 && ipparts[L]<=99 || ipparts[L]>=100 &&ipparts[L]<=255 && dot==0){
                        document.getElementById('IP').value +='.';

                    }
                }
            }
```

I need to when script put dot automatically if user put dot ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the key that was pressed was a dot or not. Also, you should use keydown, and not keyup because keydown will be fired when the key is pressed, while keyup is fired when the key is released.

```
<input name="ip" />
```

And then in your Javascript

```
var ipElement = document.querySelector('input[name=ip]');
ipElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
    // . = 190
    if(evt.keyCode == 190) {
        // Validate the rest of the IP
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Check if the user has entered 3 digits or pressed space or something

    }
});
```

Comment: `. = 190 in ASCII` --- not even close http://www.asciitable.com/. It is `dec 46` in ASCII

Comment: Why did I feel that it was 190.

Comment: @Ashwin Mukhija: `keyCode` for `.` is `190`. But keyCode != ASCII

Comment: @zerkms That's a fair bit of information I got today morning. Thank you. I always figured that keycodes were working on ASCII

Comment: @user3172276 The event handler automatically picks the pressed key from the input. You don't have to 'send' it.

Answer (score 0):

refer this document [IP validation](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/04/validate-ip-address-using-jquery.html#.Ud8U1zs3sUJ)

here he has used jqueryvalidator.js and explained with example.

```
 $.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
        var ip = "^(?:(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}" +
            "(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";
            return value.match(ip);
        }, 'Invalid IP address');

        $('#form1').validate({
            rules: {
                ip: {
                    required: true,
                    IP4Checker: true
                }
            }
        });

    });
```